# Novice trying to display MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a PHP novice, so bear with me. :)

I'm trying to edit a block of code which edits a user's profile. The title is a general 'Edit' title, but I would like to swap that out and display the first and last name of person whose profile is being edited.

The block of PHP:

```
 $modTitle = MSG_EDIT;
        $modHeader = '<a href="index.php?module=administration">'. MSG_ADMINISTRATION . '</a> &gt; <strong>' . MSG_EDIT . '</strong>';

        $SQL = sprintf(SQL_GET_USER, $id);
        $RS =& new DBRecordset();
        $RS->Open($SQL, $this->DB);
        if (!$RS->EOF()) {
            $tmpl['txtUsername'] = htmlspecialchars($RS->Field('Username'));
            $tmpl['txtFirstName'] = htmlspecialchars($RS->Field('FirstName'));
            $tmpl['txtLastName'] = htmlspecialchars($RS->Field('LastName'));
            $tmpl['txtAddress1'] = htmlspecialchars($RS->Field('Address1'));
            $tmpl['txtAddress2'] = htmlspecialchars($RS->Field('Address2'));
            $tmpl['txtCity'] = htmlspecialchars($RS->Field('City'));
            $tmpl['txtState'] = htmlspecialchars($RS->Field('State'));
            $tmpl['txtCountry'] = htmlspecialchars($RS->Field('Country'));
            $tmpl['txtPostcode'] = htmlspecialchars($RS->Field('Postcode'));
            $tmpl['txtPhone1'] = htmlspecialchars($RS->Field('Phone1'));
            $tmpl['txtPhone2'] = htmlspecialchars($RS->Field('Phone2'));
            $tmpl['txtPhone3'] = htmlspecialchars($RS->Field('Phone3'));
            $tmpl['txtEmail'] = htmlspecialchars($RS->Field('EmailAddress'));
            $tmpl['Userlist'] = '';
        }
        $RS->Close();
        unset($RS);
    }

    $this->setHeader($modTitle);
    $this->setModule($modHeader);
    $this->setTemplate('user_form', $tmpl);
    $this->Render();
// }}}
}
```

$modTitle is the generic title being displayed, with all the MSG_ references pulling static text from an external file.

How would I change $modTitle to display the full name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `if (!$RS->EOF()) {` block (before the `}` closing bracket), add this line:

```php
$modTitle = $tmpl['txtFirstName'].' '.$tmpl['txtLastName'];
```